# filtering Timestamp using jpcap

Tags: java

```
public void receivePacket(Packet packet) { 
for (byte b : ((TCPPacket)packet).option ) 

        { 
                 str += Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff) + ":"; 
                System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff) + ":"); 
        } 

    //if byte has  kind=8 and length=10, that means it has TCP Timestamp Option enabled 

    if(Pattern.matches("(.*)8:a(.*)", str)) 
        { 
                int tsval=0,tsecr=0; 
                int i = str.indexOf("8:a:"); 
                String tmp = str.substring(i+4); 

        for(int lp =1; lp<=3;lp++) 
            { 
                tmp=tmp.replaceFirst(":",""); 
            } 
        tsval = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf(":")),16); 

        tmp = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(":")+1); 
        for(int lp =1; lp<=3;lp++) 
            { 
                tmp=tmp.replaceFirst(":",""); 
            } 
        if(tmp.indexOf(":")!=-1) 
            tsecr = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf(":")),16); 
        else 
            tsecr = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(0,16)); 
            System.out.println("\tTSval: "+tsval + "\tTSecr: "+tsecr); 

        } }
```

i have found this solution online for filtering the timestamp of a tcp packet but its giving me an error on str ("cannot find variable str") can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of those variables are fields of the class you took that from. You would be better off trying to understand how that class works and then writing it from scratch rather than trying to modify their code.